# Angular 1.4.8: $http.post Prevent JSON.parse of angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular 1.4.8 and here is my $http.post

```
return $http.post($rootScope.api_url + '/jhandler', {
               data: JSON.stringify({
                   'customerId': cID,
                   'method': 'getJ',
                   'data': data
               }),
               headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf=8'}
           });
```

The response is not in json format due to some reason. Here I am facing 2 problems.

- 404 error in console.
- angular trying to parseJson throw exception in console.

404 error is okay for me. AngularJS parse the respone using JSON.parse and I want it to not parse. I want to intercept/override that function of angular which handle response.

[image: I really need to hide these errors]

Comment: your api url is wrong, and so it is returning 404, please check if you have  something in `$rootScope.api_url` and the url is correct

Comment: share your api code

Comment: Yeah, I know that api returning 404. That is not an issue. I want to avoid JSON.parse in angular $http.post

Comment: send json data, dont stringify it as it expects json

Comment: Are you certain it's 1.8? The last AngularJS version to be released is 1.7 and it hasn't released yet. 

Anyways, try removing the `JSON.stringify` call, since it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Json.stringify have nothing to do with response. The problem is with response. When server returns string, Angular.json apply Json.parse on response and it cause exception.

Comment: @TahirShahzad Then you should update your question to be more specific. Nobody seems to understand exactly what your issue is.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1:**

Send `json data`, **dont stringify it as it expects json**.

```
return $http.post($rootScope.api_url + '/jhandler', {
    data: {
        'customerId': cID,
        'method': 'getJ',
        'data': data
     }
    },
    {
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf=8'}
    }
});
```

**Issue 2:**

your `api url` is wrong, and so it is returning 404, please check if you have something in `$rootScope.api_url` and the url is correct

Comment: This is not the case. I am sending data on server. That is fine. When I receive data from server in plain string. Angular.js try to json.parse on returned data. and it cause the exception.

Comment: your api is being called? Then share your api code if so

Comment: It is not necessary to share api code. I just need help from angular geek who knows how to intercept response in angular.

Comment: I am not parsing the response, angular library is doing that and I want it to not parse response.

Answer (score 0):

there's slight problem in your code, have marked the comments

the syntax should be `$http.post(url, data, config)`
but you've merged the `data` and `config`

```
return $http.post($rootScope.api_url + '/jhandler', { /*this is data start*/
           data: JSON.stringify({
               'customerId': cID,
               'method': 'getJ',
               'data': data
           }),
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf=8'}
       }/*this is data end*/);
```

correct form:

```
return $http.post($rootScope.api_url + '/jhandler', {/*this is data start*/
           data: JSON.stringify({
               'customerId': cID,
               'method': 'getJ',
               'data': data
           })} /*this is data end*/,
           {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf=8'}}
       );
```